# Issue with Auth0 and javascript Lock v11

Tags: javascript, authentication, web, locking, auth0

I'm trying to test a basic authentication module on my web app using auth0 and Lock v1 login form.
This is a snapshot of the code I'm using:

```
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/11.23.1/lock.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/auth0variables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/auth0app.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("start");
    var lock = new Auth0Lock(AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_DOMAIN, {
        auth: {
            redirectUrl: 'undefined',
            responseType: 'code',
            params: {
                scope: 'openid email' // Learn about scopes: https://auth0.com/docs/scopes
            }
        }
    });
    lock.show();
});
</script>
```

The problem is that I'm not able to get the auth0 modal since I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of null
    at Object.getOriginFromUrl (auth0.min.esm.js:8)
    at G.run (auth0.min.esm.js:8)
    at $.checkSession (auth0.min.esm.js:8)
    at nt.getSSOData (auth0.min.esm.js:8)
    at t.getSSOData (p2_api.js:190)
    at t.getSSOData (web_api.js:64)
    at t.fetchFn (data.js:4)
    at t.fetch (cache.js:17)
    at t.get (cache.js:13)
    at r (data.js:7)
```

I don't understand if I'm configuring in a wrong way my application on Auth0 dashboard, if I'm missing some configuration parameter calling the the `Auth0Lock` method or if the issue is somewhere else. 
Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround looking at the following discussion hosted on ath0 github repo:

https://github.com/auth0/lock/issues/1638

In order to avoid `getLocationFromUrl` returning `null` value I set the `redirectUrl` option in `Auth0Lock` constructor

```
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/11.23.1/lock.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/auth0variables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/auth0app.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("start");
    var lock = new Auth0Lock(AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_DOMAIN, {
        auth: {
            redirectUrl: 'http://localhost',
            //redirectUrl: 'file://',
            responseType: 'code',
            params: {
                scope: 'openid email' // Learn about scopes: https://auth0.com/docs/scopes
            }
        }
    });
    lock.show();
});
</script>
```

Both `redirectUrl: 'http://localhost'` or `redirectUrl: 'file://'` options are working fine for my development purposes.